# Convert JSON string to XML string in Java

Tags: java, json, xml, jackson

I have the below Java class which will take a JSON file name as input and convert it to XML and create a new XML file in the same path.

```
public void convertJsonToXml(String jsonFilePath) {

    try {

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

        Products products = objectMapper.readValue(Paths.get(jsonFilePath).toFile(), Products.class);

        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        xmlMapper.writeValue(new File("./metadata/FilteredPatches.xml"), products);

    }

    catch (JsonMappingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    catch (JsonProcessingException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

But the new XML file looses the valid XML format and printing the XML data in a single line as shown below

```
<Products xmlns=""><product><product><name>FileZilla 3</name><patchuid>0003931b-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</patchuid><language>0</language></product><product><name>Notepad++ 6</name><patchuid>00038b09-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</patchuid><language>0</language></product><product><name>UltraVNC 1.2.4.0 x86</name><patchuid>00035767-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</patchuid><language>0</language></product></product></Products>
```

Any clue on what's goin wrong ? Thank you.

Comment: Underscore-java library has a static method U.jsonToXml(json).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do `xmlMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);`, before you call `xmlMapper.writeValue(...)`. And you can remove `objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);`, since you are using `objectMapper` for reading the value.

Comment: It worked, actually enable() function on ObjectMapper was erring out as I was using different version of jackson library, after using the correct version of the library the issue resolved. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I have used the following dependency                                                   
                      <dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
  </dependency>